# Join 3 tables, only use data from 2?

Tags: sql, database, oracle11g

I have 3 tables.
I need info from 2 of the tables, while the 3rd table links them.
Can someone give me an example of the joins to use?
for this example, I need insured’s first and last names, the effective date and the expiration date of their policies.

Mortal table

```
   SQL> desc mortal
 Name
 ---------------------
 MORTAL_ID
 SEX_TYPE_CODE
 FIRST_NAME
 LAST_NAME
 DOB
 MARITAL_STATUS_CODE
 SSN
 MIDDLE_NAME
 WORK_PHONE
```

Insured (linking) table

```
SQL> desc insured    
 Name
 ------------------------
 INSURED_ID
 INSURED_TYPE_CODE
 POLICY_ID
 MORTAL_ID
 BANK_ACCOUNT_NUM
 INSURED_NUM
```

Policy table

```
 SQL> desc policy
     Name
     ---------------------------
     POLICY_ID
     PLAN_ID
     POLICY_STATUS_TYPE_CODE
     PAYER_GROUP_ID
     EFFECTIVE_DATE
     POLICY_NUM
     EXPIRE_DATE
```

As you can seeI need data from tables 1 & 3 , but must use table 2 to link them.
what type of join is this? How do I use them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is still an easy join. Here is one way.

```
select m.first_name, m.last_name, p.effective_date, p.expired_date
from mortal m
  inner join policy p
    on p.policy_id = i.policy_id
  inner join insured i
    on i.mortal_id = m.mortal_id
```

Not sure what the problem is. But if the question is just "can you join a table you don't select from," then the answer is yes.

Comment: Thanks. Ive had basic DB courses(2), but just now getting into SQL. I understand the verbiage, and the logic, but joins have me pulling my hair out thus far. I'm learning though, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to join the tables.  The type of join is depended on what you are trying to acheive.  Below is a basic example:

```
SELECT a.field, c.field 
FROM [Mortal Table] a 
JOIN [Insured Table] b ON a.MORTAL_ID=b.MORTAL_ID 
JOIN [Policy Table] c on b.POLICY_ID=c.POLICY_ID 
*WHERE Clause*
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: output is supposed to be 1st name, last name, effective date, expirir date

Comment: Didn't want to write it for you but help explain :-)  But for clarity, simply put the fields you want in the select.  For example:  SELECT a.First_Name, a.Last_Name, c.Effective_Date, etc....

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
SELECT mortal.*, policy.*
FROM mortal 
INNER JOIN insured ON insured.MORTAL_ID = mortal.MORTAL_ID
INNER JOIN policy ON insured.POLICY_ID = policy .POLICY_ID
```

You can replace the inner joins with left joins to see records for every mortal.

Comment: Thanks JustinHui 
This was what I needed to see!
Does the order of the join syntax matter?

Comment: Not on INNER JOIN.  LEFT JOIN and RIGHT JOIN will make a difference depending on which table you declare first in the query.  See http://www.sql-tutorial.net/SQL-JOIN.asp